# Delphi Webservice WSDL Import

Tags: web-services, delphi, wsdl

trying to communicate with webservice, and did next steps
1.added ?wsdl to get wsdl file
2. used wsdl importer in delphi

but the problem is, i have function like

function  GetSuppliers: GetSuppliersResult; stdcall;

but there are types that are not imported

GetSuppliersResult = class(TRemotable)
  private
  published
  end;

is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the import was complete.

it is strange that you have a structure but nothing inside. the structure comes from the XSD's. you should check the XSD's

The xsd's in the wsdl file are under wsdl:types 
check if the xsd's all are accesable. do this recursivly for the xsd's to. 
this can result in missing data structures when u import.

it is also usefull to download the xsd's. so that you always have them. 
(also my delphi has a problem with long directory structures of the xsd when importing wsdl files)

hope this helps.

(another option is to send the XML by socket. but wsdl import is so much easyer)

Comment: i did that (before posting question), and even changed all wsdl  schemaLocation to file:// instead of http for each xsd) so i also suspect that problem is with .xsd file, but need to investigate more that